# How to schedule jobs to start at the beginning of each hour

Tags: python, timing

I want to schedule a task at the start of every hour , I don't want to have the initial time to when the script ,but i want the task to be started like at the start of every hour of system time in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a library called [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) made by [Dan Bader](https://github.com/dbader/) for scheduling my tasks. It is quite easy to use this and you can do like the following as mentioned in the documentation:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().hour.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

Installation:

```
pip install schedule
```

To know more ways to schedule like particular time, hour, etc, check out his documentation.